# NullPointerException cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, import, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I am using try/catch for an incorrect input for a dialog box that only accepts integers. I was told by my TA that I need to import something. I tried this but still get the same error on line 8:

```
import java.lang.NullPointerException; //put this where it should be


try
{
    buttons.rotatebutton(); //method I created
}
catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e)
{
    System.out.println("Please type a number");
    if (e == NullPointerException) //ERROR OCCURS HERE
    {
        System.out.println("User cancelled");
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if your object `e` is a NullPointerException, you have to use the operator `instanceof` instead of `==` :

```
if (e instanceof NullPointerException) {
    System.out.println("User cancelled");
}
```